# Coauthors in latex

Tags: titles

I am writing a lab report on a project that I did with two lab partners. 
In the header, we have \author{my name}.  However, I'd like to put my partners' names on the line below.

```
%Last updated 11/4/17
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, placeins,indentfirst, pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\title{Lab 3: Astrometry from CCD Images}
\author{my name
\newline {Partners: Partner 1, Partner 2}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle    
\end{document}
```

But I keep getting an error.  How do I fix this?  Thanks

Comment: Additionally how do I display latex code previews here?

Comment: I can't reproduce an error. With `\author{my name \\Partners: Partner 1, Partner 2}` i get the expected result. - Code formatting use: the code sample button `{}` (5. from the left above your code) or 4 spaces before the code.

Comment: `\newline`  has no effect in a tabular cell. Use `\\ ` as in the comment above or `\tabularnewline`. You miht also want to have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: By the way, welcome to TeX.SX. You posted a great minimal example. :-)

Comment: Perhaps a naive question but what error do you get? I get expected result too.

Comment: Is there any news here?